# django how to use range inside of kwargs

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter my queryset between two dates and I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

Here is my code

```
kwargs = {
            '{0}__{1}'.format(arg1, 'exact'): arg2,
            '{0}__{1}'.format('deleted', 'isnull'): True,
            '{0}__{1}'.format('event_date', 'range'): {date1, date2}
        }

table = GeTable(Ge.objects.filter(**kwargs))
```

I want to be able to filter my queryset to only records between date1 and date2. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You pass a 2-tuple, so:

```
kwargs = {
    '{0}__{1}'.format(arg1, 'exact'): arg2,
    '{0}__{1}'.format('deleted', 'isnull'): True,
    '{0}__{1}'.format('event_date', 'range'): (date1, date2)
}

table = GeTable(Ge.objects.filter(**kwargs))
```

By using a set, the order can vary between different runs, and thus sometimes it will work, and at some moments it will not (roughly around 50%). This is because of the randomized hashing algorithm, which is used as a protective measure for security reasons.